Problems with firebase predeploy script
I have the following predeploy script in as firebase.json file:
{
    "hosting": [
        { 
            "target": "frontend",
            "predeploy": "cd functions && yarn build && cd ..",
            "public": "frontend/dist",
            "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
        }
    ]
}

The predeploy script is not running the yarn build command properly. The yarn build command is supposed to run tsc.
I've added which yarn to the predeploy command and got /Users/opening/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.1/bin/yarn
So yarn is recognized. Anyone have any ideas why the build command isn't running properly

What is the problem?

It doesn't run yarn build and just moves on

You might want to try the simpler yarn --cwd functions build

good tip. Tried it but it still doesn't work

Too add more information to this problem. The yarn I was previously using was through the corepack enable functionality that is now part of 18+. Something with that doesn't work with the firebase predeploy
